# How to default context.WebSockets.WebSocketRequestedProtocols on ASP.NET Core server if nothing is passed from Client

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket

I am trying to connect to asp.net core server using websocket. I need to set the default value for context.WebSockets.WebSocketRequestedProtocols if nothing is passed from the client side.
Currently from Postman if I am passing key value in the header(key: Sec-WebSocket-Protocol, value: desiredValue) it is working. But Connection is not established if nothing is getting passed, So trying to default this value on the server.

Comment: perfect :) thanks for it key: Sec-WebSocket-Protocol, value: desiredValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to change the header in a websocket request on server side. And "context.WebSockets.WebSocketRequestedProtocols" is readonly.

You could use `context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync(subProtocol: "myprotocol")` to only accept "myprotocol" connection or `context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync()` to accept any connection as null protocol.

Such as below sample:
Server

```
app.Map("/ws", async context =>
{
    var h=context.Request.Headers;
    var a = context.WebSockets.WebSocketRequestedProtocols;

    if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        using (var webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await webSocket.SendAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"Test - {DateTime.Now}"), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    }
});
```

Client

```
using (var ws = new ClientWebSocket())
{
    ws.Options.AddSubProtocol("jwt");
    await ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://localhost:6666/ws"), CancellationToken.None);
    var buffer = new byte[256];
    while (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        var result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
        if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
        {
            await ws.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, null, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count));
        }
    }
}
```

Test
[image]

So you could check if `context.WebSockets.WebSocketRequestedProtocols.FirstOrDefault()` is null. If it is null, use `context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync()` to make it default. 
If it is not null,  use `context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync(subProtocol: $"{myprotocol}")`